# Null inject beans for Servlet Filter with xml configuration

Tags: xml, spring, filter, config, javabeans

i have created **JWT filter** for spring security.
When app is running, the filter is executed, the fields that should have been **injected are null (SessionDao  and TokenService)**
For that classes(SessionDao  and TokenService) i have added annotation and they works well also add in spring-config.xml Beans

```
 <bean id="sessionDao" class="com.dao.impl.SessionDaoImpl" scope="prototype"/>

<bean id="tokenService" class="com.service.impl.TokenServiceImpl" scope="prototype"/>
```

Also was trying with @Autowired

Other Filter works well (CorsFilter(Have no injected fields))

JwtFilter class below

```
@Component
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JwtFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
private static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";

private final SessionDao sessionDao;

private final TokenService tokenService;

private final Logger log = new LoggerUtil().getLogger();

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain 
filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    String token = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER);
    try {
        Authentication authentication = tokenService.getAuthentication(token);
        if (authentication != null) {
            AuthorizedUser authorizedUser = (AuthorizedUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
            SessionEntity session = sessionDao.getByJwtId(authorizedUser.getJwtId());
            if (!session.isDeleted()) {
                session.setLastActivityTime(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                sessionDao.save(session);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Enabled by web.xml
....

cors
rsoft.component.SimpleCORSFilter

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>JwtFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.component.JwtFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>JwtFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

</filter-mapping>
...
```

If I delete in JwtFilter @NoArgsConstructor (force = true) or the default constructor in the class, then I get a compilation error, since the default constructor for the JwtFilter class will remain in web.xml
In that line

```
<filter-class>com.component.JwtFilter</filter-class>
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the context will not have a bean yet, if you use the xml configuration, either manually write the bean creation, or use annotations

```
public void init(FilterConfig cfg) { 
    ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils
      .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(cfg.getServletContext());
    this.bean = ctx.getBean(YourBeanType.class);
}
```